# How do I verify that a post request is from my website?

Tags: php, sql, http

**How do I verify that a post request is from my website and not an attacker?**

I currently have a php script (in xampp) which accepts a post request containing an email. The php script fetches all user information correlating to that email from a phpmyadmin database, and echos it for my script to use.

My question is, (once I publish the site) how can I authenticate who is sending the email (via post) to the server, so that anyone who knows a user's email can't just steal their information?

Comment: You can send some session variable and check if this is set executing submit

Comment: Using a CSRF token might help you. If you google CSRF token you can find out all about them easily. And/or use authentication. It depends on the precise use case

Answer (score 0):

You'll need some kind of authentication mechanism.

If you don't wanna implement an authentication (email + password), you could send an email to this address containing a link which authenticates this email and is valid for a limited time. Clicking on this link would lead the user to his user information.

Answer (score 0):

Use csrf token something like this

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) { if (!hash_equals($_SESSION['csrf'], $_POST['csrf'])) die();
```

And inside form

```
<input name="csrf" type="hidden" value="<?php echo escape($_SESSION['csrf']); ?>">
```